# Prime numbers iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I wrote a piece of code to print n prime numbers:

```
class PrimeGen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = 2
    def genPrime(self, num):
        for i in range(num):
            while 1:
                for j in range(2, self.current/2 + 1):
                    if self.current % j == 0:
                        self.current = self.current + 1
                        break
                else:
                    break
            print self.current,
            self.current = self.current + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PrimeGen()
    p.genPrime(5)
```

The code works fine. I get `2 3 5 7 11` as output. I tried to make the class `iterable`. Code below. But the output is `0 1 2 3 4`. I could not quite figure out where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
class PrimeIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = 1

    def next(self):
        self.current = self.current + 1
        while 1:
            for i in range(2, self.current/2 + 1):
                if self.current % i == 0:
                    self.current = self.current + 1
                    break # Break current for loop
            else:
                break # Break the while loop and return
        return self.current

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PrimeIter()
    for p in range (5):
        print p,
```

Comment: The `next`method is deprecated and you're not even using the class you created. Just using the range

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! Dumb oversight... I have been debugging for a while!!

Comment: This is a really slow way to generate primes.  If you've got an upper limit on your primes, then the sieve of Erastothenes will perform better.

Comment: @misha: Thanks. i m just trying out some examples to learn iterators! generating prime numbers is not my intention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using this code to print out the values:

```
for p in range (5):
    print p,
```

If you look at that, it's printing the values of the range. You probably want to print things from the prime iterator. [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) has some functions that may help:

```
for prime in itertools.islice(p, 5):
    print prime,
```

Additionally, you may want to consider using a generator:

```
def primes():
    current = 1
    while True:
        current += 1
        while True:
            for i in xrange(2, current // 2 + 1):
                if current % i == 0:
                    current += 1
                    break
            else:
                break
        yield current
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest. +1

Comment: Your xrange is formatted incorrectly (part of it is currently displayed a comment). I'd edit myself, but edits must be 6 characters or more, for some reason.

Comment: @Symmetric: Python comments start with `#`. `//` in Python is explicit integer division. The syntax highlighter must not be recognizing it as Python.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I wasn't aware of the '//' operator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are reusing the variable `p` in your test code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PrimeIter() # first declaration of p
    for p in range (5): # second declaration of p
        print p,   # uses second declaration of p
```

I'd recommend using `itertools.islice` to get the first 5 elements of an iterator:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PrimeIter()
    for x in itertools.islice(p, 5):
        print x,
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterator for generating prime numbers upto some maximum m:

```
class PrimeIter: 
    def ___init__(self, m): 
       self.max = m

    def __iter__(self):
       self.n = 1
       return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n < self.max:
           self.n += 1
           i = 2
           while i < (self.n//2+1):
                if self.n % i == 0:
                   self.n = self.n+1
                   if self.n > self.max:
                       raise StopIteration
                   i = 1
                i += 1
           else:
                return self.n
       else:
            raise StopIteration

 p = PrimeIter (100)        
 for i in p:
     print(i, end=' ')
```